# Type or namespace could not be found (SCHEMA added)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-sourcesafe

A schema was added to a .NET project and was build succesfully. Afterwards the new resource was checked in. Now in another computer cannot be build, states that "Type or namespace  could not be found (are you missing an assembly reference?)". Any ideas to overceome this issue?

Comment: What type of schema was added?

Comment: It is a DataSet with a single table.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are missing an assembly which might live outside of your source code repository (e.g., installed under Program Files).  This is often the case with third-party code.  If you look under References, you might see that there is a missing reference.

Comment: I am not sure that after the creation of the schema produces an assembly. Prior to the creation of the schema the project was built succesfully.